# IE when do duplicate tab pass information from parent tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in ERP system, It has company dropdown in the header. When the user selects duplicate tab in IE. I need to pass selected company to duplicate tab.

ie, is there any way to pass information to duplicate tab from which it was created (parent tab).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to share data or events between browser tabs? Also always specify which version of IE

Comment: Yes i want to share data/event between browser tabs. I need to support from IE9 and greater versions

Answer (score 0):

You can share events/data using LocalStorage on the same domain. Note that the `storage` event won't work unless on a real domain (http:// not file://) and also doesn't work in iframes on codepen/jsfiddle etc:

```
function onStorageChange(e) {
  console.log('storage changed:', e)
}

window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageChange);

window.localStorage.setItem('someItem', 'a value');
```

If you set up an event callback like that, and call `setItem` in one tab, the event will also occur in the other tab as they share the same local storage.